# What is the best way to display form data in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, output, simple-form, formtastic

I am very new to Rails.

I am looking for the most common and 'rails-like' way to display the output of form data. I know that Simple form and Formtastic are good options to write concise code and display input fields in a user friendly manner. However, I am looking for something slightly different, I want to display the data from these forms as output, and I want to do it in a similar and concise manner. I haven't been able to find anything the last few days that I have been searching around so I figured I should ask Stack Overflow.

What do you normally do:

Write custom helpers to be able to write concise code and display the output data?

Use Simpleform/Formtastic, disable the fields, and modify the css to 
   make it look the way you want?

Is there a common gem that does this? Or perhaps another way I haven't thought about.

First, thanks for the initial responses. I thought I should clarify my question. Since the answers don't quite hit the mark. I already have a show method in the controller, as well as a view template for it. Currently I am displaying each field individually in the form for about 12 fields using form_for. See example snippet below:

```
  <%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
     <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span6">
       <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

         <%= f.label :title %>
         <%= f.text_field :title, :disabled => true %>

         <%= f.label :start_date %>
         <%= f.date_field :start_date, :disabled => true %>
      </div>
     </div>
   <% end %>
```

**I guess maybe a better question would be, is their an equivalent to form_for method that display data for users, not to edit it but just to read it?** It seems like their would be a a standard way to do it that I haven't discovered.

Comment: By 'display form data' do you mean just the show view of your controller? It's separate from your form and should probably be displayed differently.

Comment: There is not a single best way. It is your choice, but do it in your "show.html.erb" view file. (I like using HAML)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to build forms is to use `rails g scaffold Example name:string` This would generate the Model, Views, Controller, and the necessary database migrations for a Model named Example with a Name attribute that is a string.

You would then use html and css to style the view how you want.

There is a ton of useful info for you on the rails guides [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate).

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is rather ambiguous, you must appreciate that this functionality is *exactly* what Rails is built for (submit data & be able to display / manipulate it somewhere else)

---

**Data**

The data in an `MVC` application is bound by one very important factor - a **database**

If you're submitting data through a form, your goal is to store it in your database, and display it in other views / controller methods

Therefore, the blunt question to your answer is to abide by [MVC processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), and save your data to a central repository (database or other), which you can call later:

[image]

---

**View**

To get your data into your data store, you first need to submit it

The `view` part of MVC is where you can display your UI, and consequently is where you can put your form. There is a whole tutorial about how to design this [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), but for demonstrations' sake, here's an example of how you'd use your form:

```
#app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :body %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Controller**

The data you input into your view will be sent to your controller on save

The data is sent via the HTML `POST` method to be read by Rails as a `params[]` hash. This hash contains all the sent items from your HTML form, and can be used like this:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def new
    @post = Post.new
end 

def create 
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
end

private
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

---

**Model**

The `.save` method on your newly created `Post` object, basically tells your model to put the data into your database (or other data store), which you can then pull later (using the `.find` method or similar)

```
#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   #stuff here
end
```

It's important to note your models don't *store* your data, they simply provide an interface (API if you will) to save the data into some sort of data store (namely, a DB)

Models are super important because they allow you to structure & relate your data, creating the ability to deploy really deep & powerful applications